# codecademy javascript math

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to complete the following on codecademy:

Complete the missing bits of code to construct the if / else statement. Make the condition evaluate to true.
Finish the else statement by printing out the string "Error Error Error" to the console.

I entered this:

```
 if ("Jon".length * 2 / (2 + 1) === 2) {
   console.log("true");
 } else {
   console.log("Error Error Error");
 }
```

I am lost and exasperated, please help!

But it tells me this: Oops, try again. Make sure your if/else statement evaluates to true!

Comment: You can try to find answers here - https://github.com/ummahusla/codecademy-stuff/tree/master/JavaScript

Comment: That would print out `true` ... what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that you changed the first console log from "The answer makes sense!" to "true", which is not what the validator expects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `Codecademy`, there are a lot of different exercises, where you can't just pass them, so easy.

**Most common problems:**
Syntax problem - Everything seems to be working, but it might by syntax problem.

**Code formatting** - as an example:

*PASS:*

```
 if ("Jon".length * 2 / (2 + 1) === 2) {
   console.log("true");
 } else {
   console.log("Error Error Error");
 }
```

*WILL NOT PASS:*

```
 if ("Jon".length * 2 / (2 + 1) === 2) { console.log("true");} else {
   console.log("Error Error Error");
 }
```

**Browser Issue** - Try different browser, sometimes it help.

PS. I've did almost 1300 exercise and I've been forcing these bugs quite often.